# Robotic Process Automation tags creation on stackoverflow

Tags: blueprism, rpa, uipath, automationanywhere, workfusion

I am posting this question to create RPA - Robotic Process Automation tags like blueprism, automationnanywhere, roboticprocessautomation, rpa and workfusion. Once all tags are in place then this will help organizing all the questions at one place.

Robotic process automation (or RPA) is an emerging form of clerical process automation technology based on the notion of software robots or artificial intelligence (AI) workers.

Source - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robotic_process_automation

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Love the initiative!

I would suggest tags like `automationanywhere`, `blueprism` etc (full tool names) and one generic, parent tag `rpa`. So delete the `roboticprocessautomation` tag.